# multiple variables check with preg_match

Tags: php, validation

I'm running checks to validate a form, and I'm trying to use preg_match like follows:

```
}else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$firstName)){
   //code
}
```

however, I want to check several variables, like `$lastName, $address,` etc...

How can I include them in the checking process withouth calling preg_match to every singe variable?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the regex for? How can one single regex apply to every variable which has it's own purpose?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check that a string is alphanumerical use http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php. This will be much easier.

```
if (ctype_alnum($firstName) && ctype_alnum($lastName) && ctype_alnum($address)) {
     //they are all alphanumerical
}
```

alternatively if you need to run your own validation multiple times you can create your own function and call that the same way

```
if (validate_inputs($firstName) && validate_inputs($lastName) && validate_inputs($address)) {
     //it is an alphanumerical string
}
function validate_inputs($input) {
    return preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $input);//i changed the quantifier so the string must contain a character as well
}
```